# C# Index out of range exception when clearly isn't and works with certain values but not others?

Tags: c#, list, exception, indexing

currently I'm writing an investment game to help further my self teaching in c#. That aside I need a bit of help with a certain exception:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Okay, I've had this before, racked my brain and I'd made the tiniest mistake when setting a for loop's max value to the wrong one, and yeah I guess when you see this error you think rookie mistake. And it may be, but I've been scanning this code for a while now trying to figure it out and can't seem to find what's wrong! It feels as if the program is tripping over itself.

Here's the code:

```
private void buttonBuyComm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int buyAmount;
        int.TryParse(commBuyText.Text, out buyAmount);
        int itemNumber;
        int.TryParse(commItem.Text, out itemNumber);

        if (buyAmount <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            addListComm();

            for (int i = 0; i <= maxCommShares; i++)
            {
                if (Share[i].OrderNumber == itemNumber) // This is where I get the error
                {
                    if (Share[i].MaxShares > Share[i].OwnedShares)
                    {
                        decimal totalSharePrice = buyAmount * Share[i].Value;
                        if (totalSharePrice <= money)
                        {
                            money = money - totalSharePrice;
                            Share[i].OwnedShares = Share[i].OwnedShares + buyAmount;
                            if (Share[i].Value > Share[i].boughtAt)
                            {
                                Share[i].boughtAt = Share[i].Value;
                            }

                            updateLabels();
                            updateLists();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You do not have enough money!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You already own all the shares!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So that's my buy button, there's a text box beside it (buyAmount), and another for the selling button which has almost identical code and works fine, and another for the item number. At the moment I have 5 shares, (share1 - share5) which all get added to the list Share by the method `'addListComm();'`.

The list is cleared before the values are added, in the method, so it works fine. Considering this snippet of code is used several times in my program and this error only occurs here? Weird if you ask me. Yes, I will comment my code after I've finished it.

So anyway, the problem occurs when I go to buy a legitimate amount of shares in share1 - share4, but not share5. And when I go to buy more shares than I have money, it works fine and provides the

> "You do not have enough money" message box.

When I buy say, for example, 20 shares in share1, I'm provided with the `out of index exception`, when the value for i is 0, and the place in the list of share1 is 0. When I buy 5 shares in share5 (place 4) then it works perfect. The worst thing is this worked the first time, perfectly and I was so pleased, then I wrote the code for the sell button and now it doesn't work. However nothing in the sell button interferes with the buy button, and doesn't run at the same time anyway. Plus to be sure I deleted the sell buttons code and ran it, but received the same error.

Why does this error only occur when I choose to buy a perfectly acceptable amount of shares using a list and for loop that works EVERYWHERE else? maxCommShares is right as well, I've triple checked, and I get an error for the first value in the list anyway?

Sorry for the wall of text.

Edit: Thanks everyone for the useful information, and taking the time to reply. That was very quick! A user called RJM commented asking if 'updateLists()' was interfering with the list, it did have the same method 'addListComm()' inside it, and I'm so ashamed I missed it! Cheers all for the advice though! And if I'm doing this wrong sorry, I don't use stack overflow much, but it seems pretty awesome!

Comment: Where does `maxCommShares` come from?  Are you sure it's greater than zero?  Also if it is, what if `Share[i]` isn't the max size?  If `maxCommShares` is 6, but `Share[]` is only of size 5, you'll get that error.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and check where it throws and what value it's trying.

Comment: Couple questions: 1) what is `maxCommShares` being set to?  If it's not being set to the length of `Share`, that's an issue.  2) what is `updateLists()` doing?  Is it modifying the `Share` list at all?  If it's modifying the contents of `Share` while you're in the middle of looping over it, that's a problem too.

Comment: maxCommShares is set to 4. there's share's 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 added to the list Share. Update Lists updates the tables I'm using, it also uses 'addListComm();' except like I said, whenever that method is run it clears the values at the start. Should I perhaps move that outside of the loop?

Comment: RJM - you were right, 'updateLists()' was interfering with it I believe, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you declare your `Share` array as

```
ShareType Share[maxCommShares]
```

then the index of the array can change from `0` to `maxCommShares-1`. In your code you use the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxCommShares; i++)
```

which tries to access the element `Share[maxCommShares]`, which produces the error. You should change the loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxCommShares; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies here : `for (int i = 0; i <= maxCommShares; i++)`.

When using numbered indexes I should always be smaller and never equal to the right side variable, in this case `maxCommShares` This is called an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

There fore the correct way is `for (int i = 0; i < maxCommShares; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

> So anyway, the problem occurs when I go to buy a legitimate amount of shares in share1 - share4, but not share5

Sounds like since you are looping through the max number of shares, but in the case of 1-4, your loop still does 5, but share 5 doesn't exist.

If you are really putting them in a List<> then you can use a foreach loop and always have the correct number of runs.

In your code somewhere else

```
private List<Share> shareList = new List<Share>();
```

where ever you add shares

```
Share share1 = new Share();
share1.orderNumber = 1;

shareList.Add(share1);
```

then in your button press you can do

```
private void buttonBuyComm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int buyAmount;
    int.TryParse(commBuyText.Text, out buyAmount);
    int itemNumber;
    int.TryParse(commItem.Text, out itemNumber);

    if (buyAmount <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        addListComm();

        foreach(Share s in shareList)
        {
            if (s.OrderNumber == itemNumber) // This is where I get the error
            {
                if (s.MaxShares > s.OwnedShares)
                {
                    decimal totalSharePrice = buyAmount * s.Value;
                    if (totalSharePrice <= money)
                    {
                        money = money - totalSharePrice;
                        s.OwnedShares = s.OwnedShares + buyAmount;
                        if (s.Value > s.boughtAt)
                        {
                            s.boughtAt = s.Value;
                        }

                        updateLabels();
                        updateLists();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You do not have enough money!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You already own all the shares!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```